# Flatten curve of array of numbers

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to find the technique of Normalising (not sure if that is the right word) a range of numbers.

Say I have an array:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 70, 80, 900]

I want to flatten or average out the range curve, so it's more like:

[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 50, 100, 300]. // not a real calculation

So increasing the smaller numbers in relation to reducing the larger numbers.

What is this technique called? Normalised scale? I wish to implement this in some Javascript.

UPDATE: Here is hopefully a better description of what I'm trying to do:

I have an original array of numbers:

```
[0, 10, 15, 50, 70, 100]
```

When processed through a `function averageOutAllNumbers(array, slider)` will produce and array that when `slider` is set to 100% looks like:

```
[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100] // the curve has been flattened
```

when slider is set to `0%`, it will return the original array. If `slider` is set to `50%`, the returned array will look *something* like:

```
[0, 12, 19, 52, 88, 100] // the curve is less steep [do not take these number literally, I'm guess what the output would be based on the slider].
```

the `array.max()` will alway be `100`.

Comment: The first step to coming up with an algorithm is describing it un-ambiguously. Come up with details so that there _is_ a "real" calculation, then write some code.

Comment: Please specify what becoming “more like” the desired result actually means. Normalizing would usually be dividing each number by the element with the largest absolute value, for example.

Comment: Maybe multiply or add to each number by something proportional to its ratio to the geometric mean of the whole array, or something like that?

Comment: "Normalizing" implies that you are converting the range to some predetermined "normal" scale (for example, 1-10). This sounds like something else. What is the use case here? You are going to have to be more specific about how the numbers should get from point A to point B and _why_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments so far, they did point me closer to the solution.
No thanks to the trolls who down-voted; if you can't fix it no one can—right!

When I updated my question I realised that *"increasing the smaller numbers in relation to reducing the larger numbers"* would eventually lead to an evenly distributed set of numbers, e.g. `[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]`. However I did actually want something like I stated in the question: `[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100] // the curve has been flattened`. I did some more searching for things like:

- Evenly space an array of oddly spaced numbers
- Making a list of evenly spaced numbers in a certain range
- Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval
- Find what percent X is between two numbers

Amongst the list of search result I saw the answer to my original question: *"What is this technique called?"* **[Linear Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)**

Based on that I was able to create the following:

```
var orig = [3, 11, 54, 72, 100];

function lerp(n, x0, x1) {
    // returns a position: x that is n percent between y0 and y1
    // As numbers in array are x only, y values are fixed to 0(start) - 1(end)
    const y0 = 0;
    const y1 = 1;
    const x = ((y1 - n)*x0 + (n - y0)*x1) / (y1 - y0);

    return x;
}

var flattenedEven = orig.map((value, index, arr) => {
    return lerp(1, value, (Math.max(...arr)/arr.length) * (index + 1));
});

//=> [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]

var flattenedCurve = orig.map((value, index, arr) => {
    return lerp(.7, value, (Math.max(...arr)/arr.length) * (index + 1));
});

//=> [14.9, 31.3, 58.2, 77.6, 100]
```